# Cleanly terminating asynchronous process after it reads stdin

Tags: subprocess, async

I'm starting a process with `start-process` and immediately calling `set-process-sentinel` to get notifications when it ends. After attaching the sentinel I send the buffer's contents to the process's stdin followed by EOF, like this:

`(process-send-region proc (point-min) (point-max))
(process-send-eof proc)`

I'm seeing the correct output in the process's output buffer, so I know it's working correctly to some degree.

But my sentinel reports that the process ends with event "exited abnormally with code 1", but I would like the process to end normally with the "finished" event. Why am I seeing this abnormal exit? What can I do to get a normal exit?

Comment: Probably depends on the process...

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was being dense. The process is correctly exiting with a 1, but I was naively expecting 0.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was doing this correctly, and the process was correctly returning a 1 result. So the posted code is the correct thing to do.